# How to upload the image and store it in database?

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008

I want the vb.net coding for upload the image from local machine and store it in database

Comment: http://www.lightcubesolutions.com/blog/?p=209 GridFS is a way to handle that

Comment: @Jeong: sorry, this site was correctly not opened. please give another solution

Comment: @Sunitha: GridFS is for mongoDB. You can store image itself in DB

Answer (score 1):

There's got to be a gazillion of samples and solutions for this out here - did you even try Google???

Check out e.g. these links:

- [File Upload and Save Submitted Files to SQL Server 2005, Sample ASP.NET Web Site Application](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/file-upload-and-save-to-sql-server.aspx)
- [Storing and Retrieving Images/Files In Sql Server - VB.NET](http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/29583-Storing-Retrieving-Files-In-Sql-Server.aspx)

And a **great many more!**